# awk - store first occurrence based on cell

Tags: awk

I have a file (around 10k entries) with following format:

```
text1;text2;text3;lat;long
A;B;C;55.01;12.01
A;B;C;n/a;n/a
D;E;F;56.011;13.099
D;E;F;56.01;13.01
D;E;F;n/a;n/a
I;B;C;n/a;n/a
```

containing duplicates, some without, others with mildly contradicting LAT;LONG coordinates.

I only want to store first unique value of `[$1;$2;$3;$4;$5]` as output, so desired output should look like:

```
text1;text2;text3;lat;long
A;B;C;55.01;12.01
D;E;F;56.011;13.099
I;B;C;n/a;n/a
```

I'd assume that I want to create an array, but I struggle with proper formating of it... so any help appreciated !

Comment: please add your attempted awk command

Comment: Even if your solution isn't working, you can share it in the question

Comment: Looks like a double `SUBSEP` challenge.

Comment: Regarding `I only want to store first unique value of [$1;$2;$3;$4;$5] as output` - not according to your expected output which looks like you want to print the first unique value of either `[$1]` or `[$1,$2]` or `[$1;$2;$3]`. If you [edit] your question to clarify which combination of the fields you want treated as a unique key then we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm glad you have it working, but personally, I would suggest something a little more along the lines of:

```bash
$  awk -F";" '!seen[$1,$2,$3] {print; seen[$1,$2,$3]=1}' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your data in `file`, you could then do:

```
$ awk -F";" '!seen[$1,$2,$3] {print; seen[$1,$2,$3]=1}' file
text1;text2;text3;lat;long
A;B;C;55.01;12.01
D;E;F;56.011;13.099
I;B;C;n/a;n/a
```

You can shorten it to about your example (which simply checks if the unique index of the first three fields combined has been set yet and relies on the default `print` operation to output the first records having the unique combination):

```bash
$ awk -F";" '!seen[$1,$2,$3]++' file
```

However, using the joined fields `$1,$2,$3` as the index is about the only way you can ensure uniqueness.

If you say your works, then it is certainly shorter. Let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score -1):

Found it by stopping to look for creating arrays

 created a new $1 being $1,$2,$3, but the other solutions is indeed more elegant, here is the command I came up with after merging the fields in the file (and setting them as new $1), which I then didn't have to do 
`awk -F';' '!seen[($1)]++' file1.csv > file2.csv`

Comment: You're right, sorry, I corrected my comment.